# Is it possible to check certain checkboxes based on linkbutton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've got a page where I'm trying to customize a "language group" for a project-management app. (We do artwork projects that often require translations, and I want to be able to let the user click on a linkbutton (or other control) to group certain languages together. They might click a "Latin America" button, and that would check all the languages I define to be in that group. I don't want to RESTRICT or LIMIT their choice; I just want the button to simply precheck a bunch of boxes to make the process more efficient.

I have a table of all the languages, with IDs, and then I have another table with Language Groups (with the `LanguageID` and a `LanguageGroupID`).

The linkbutton would pass a "`LanguageGroupID`" and then the boxes would become checked if their `LanguageID` was found in the `LanguageGroup` table and corresponded to that `LanguageGroupID`.

I built it another way, that has checkboxes for the `LanguageGroups`, and when you check it, it displays those languages, but it's messy and it's not working the way I want it to. I'd show you that code, but I'm abandoning that method!

So, does anyone have some basic examples of how I would do this?

Comment: is it a mvc.net project view or a asp.net web page? There will be Javascript (or ajax) in the answer

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished any number of ways.  Client side, you could use javascript.  One scenarios would be to have a column in your language table that has the language type (this could be visible or hidden).  When the user checks a language type, this could fire a javascript event that iterates over the language table, looking for values in the language type column.  If it matches, check it.  This can all be done through the use of the Document Object Model.

Or, if you're using asp.net with code behind, you could implement a gridview, inside an update panel, that is attached to a datasource you create (a list of classes that have language and language type values).  When the user checks the language type, a partial post back occurs.  You can then iterate over the gridview's datasource and check the appropriate check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you're saying as a user I would want to click some button for "Latin America" and then a series of checkboxes would become checked, so PortugueseCB, SpanishCB, etcCB... Also it sounds like you have 3 items: Languages, Language ID, LanguageGroupId.
What you could do is create a class that contains the id and the language

```
public class LanguageIdent
{
public int ID; 
public string Language 
}
```

Then create another class that contains a list of these

```
public class LanguageGroup
{
public List<LanguageIdent> LanguageID; 
}
```

From there you can initialize and create methods as you see fit. Also you use the all the methods given to lists which is awesome. You could implement your check system perhaps like

```
private void SpanishCB_checkChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
LanguageGroup LG = new LanguageGroup(); 
for(int i =0; i<LG.Count(); i++)
{
if(LG.LanguageID.ID == LatinAmericaID)
{
int index = checkedListBox1.IndexOf(nL.LanguageID[i].Language);
checkedListBox.SetItemsChecked(index, checked(CheckState.Checked));
}
}
}
```

So in your form you would have a checkedListBox which you could arrange any way you want, alphabetically, region, etc. Then when the user checked "Latin America" only places languages belonging to that id will be checked. Hope this helps.